# Juntar duas Arraylist

Tags: java, array

Fiz um `ArrayList` (`nomeTimes`) que recebe uma quantidade de nomes de times conforme o `for` abaixo:

```
  for(int i = 0; i<numeroTimes;i++){
        String nomeTime=entrada.next();
        nomeTimes.add(nomeTime);
    }
```

Minha ideia é duplicar essa `ArrayList` e embaralhar com:

```
Collections.shuffle(nomeTimes);
```

E juntar os dados das duas `Arraylists` em uma terceira.

No caso é pra montar uma tabela com os confrontos dos times. Os confrontos armazenados na  terceira `ArrayList` ficariam por exemplo assim: `[[a,b][a,c][a,d],[[b,a],[b,c],[b,d]]`.

Como unir as duas em uma terceira?

Comment: Você quer montar uma ArrayList que possui os confrontos? Poderia nos dizer como espera que fique cada String nessa terceira ArrayList?

Comment: Isso, pensei em por exemplo, 4 times, e todos jogam entre si, ficaria tipo [[a,b][a,c][a,d],[[b,a],[b,c],[b,d]] e por ai vai, acho que seria melhor pra manipular ou to complicando demais?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pensei da seguinte forma: Ao invés de ter dois `ArrayList`s você precisa apenas de um, que possui o nome dos times. Daí você faz uma permutação 1 a 1, eliminando os casos em que o time se enfrentaria, e armazenaria em uma segunda `ArrayList` chamada `confrontos`. Após definidos os confrontos você embaralha eles. Exemplo:

```
public class CalculaConfrontos {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> nomesTimes = new ArrayList<String>();
        nomesTimes.add("a");
        nomesTimes.add("b");
        nomesTimes.add("c");
        nomesTimes.add("d");
        ArrayList<String> confrontos = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(String t1: nomesTimes) {
            for(String t2: nomesTimes) {
                if(t1 == t2) continue;
                confrontos.add("[" + t1 + "," + t2 + "]");
            }
        }
        Collections.shuffle(confrontos);
        for(String c: confrontos) {
            System.out.println(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Resultado:

> [a,c]
>   [b,c]
>   [c,a]
>   [c,b]
>   [a,d]
>   [b,d]
>   [d,c]
>   [d,a]
>   [d,b]
>   [c,d]
>   [a,b]
>   [b,a]